# Cant access subclass methods of object in Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to store objects that are only a subclass of an Abstract Class.  However, I can only see the abstract class methods and none of the subclass methods. What have I missed?

Class with Error in:

```
class CharacterStats
{
    private Dictionary<StatType, Stat> playerStats;

    //Contructor for new game
    public CharacterStats()
    {

        playerStats = new Dictionary<StatType, Stat>();

        //Creates all Stats with default values
        playerStats.Add(StatType.STA, new StatSta());
        playerStats.Add(StatType.STR, new StatStr());
        playerStats.Add(StatType.DEX, new StatDex());
        playerStats.Add(StatType.DEF, new StatDef());

    }

    //Returns the damage reduction in %
    public int GetDamageReduction()
    {
        playerStats[StatType.DEF].  //Missing Methods from StatDef class
        //Added to remove error message
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Abstract Class:**

```
 abstract class Stat
 {
    protected int pointsAdded;
    protected int pointCap;

    public Stat() {}

    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "Working!";
    }

 }
```

**Subclass:**

```
class StatDef : Stat
{

    public StatDef() : base()
    {
        this.pointsAdded = 0;
        this.pointCap = 100;
    }

    public int ApplyDamageReduction(int dmg)
    {
        //removed data to read easier
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your dictionary is typed to `Stat`, not the subclass. The compiler has no idea what the actual subclass could be at runtime, so you must cast it to the subclass yourself first - provided you know what the subclass is.

Comment: @Dai this should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the expression `playerStats[StatType.DEF]` is just `Stat`. The compiler doesn't know what kind of `Stat` is stored as the value there.

If it will *always* be a `StatDef`, then you should just cast:

```
var def = (StatDef) playerStats[StatType.DEF];
// Now you can use def.ApplyDamageReduction etc
```

However, you'll need to cast *any* time you want to use a stat-specific member. Unless you often want to treat multiple stats in the same way, I'd suggest ditching the dictionary approach and just having separate fields:

```
class CharacterStats
{
    private StatDefence defence;
    private StatAttack attack;
    private StatStrength strength;
    // etc
}
```

You could easily write a method that allows you to iterate over all the stats for the times where that *is* useful:

```
public IReadOnlyList<Stat> GetAllStats() =>
    new Stat[] { defence, attack, strength, ... };
```

But my suspicion is that *most* of the time you're using the stats, you actually want to know a specific stat. I'd always rather write:

```
var strength = stats.Attack;
```

than

```
var strength = stats[StatType.STR];
```

even if when I *don't* need the specific aspects of the strength statistic.

Comment: I was planning on calculating multiple different values within each stat such as damage reduction as well as storing how many points are in each and the total points allowed.  Is it possible for the dictionary value to be a subclass of as this would work really well if i could do this or something similar.  Also the other reason I wanted to use Dictionary was in the future I was going to include more stats and thought this was a nice way of grouping all these objects.

Comment: @HamishKendall: The value is already a reference to the instance of the subclass. But you shouldn't expect the compile-time type of the result of a dictionary lookup to be "the type you happen to want it to be" - it's the type that you've specified as the second type argument to the `Dictionary<,>`. Yes, you can certainly have commonality in your abstract base class, but I'm still unconvinced that a dictionary is the best way of approaching this. You have a specific set of keys, and you know the type of the result for each key - which makes it sound much more like a collection of fields to me.